# Return static response code and continue in laravel function

Tags: php, laravel

If i call test function from api request, i always need status 200 whatever the execution is inside the function.

```
{
     whatever the execution(even if it gives status 400),
     i need to get response 200 without using try catch
}
```

or can i return at first and execute the remaining
like

```
public function test()
{
   return something;
   other execution here;
}
```

Comment: You can't run code below return in a function.

Comment: why do you want to return status and then do something else?

Comment: You can delegate "other execution here" to queue job and leave it executes then return "something".

Comment: Suppose i called function from anywhere else, 
i want to run my code witout any error whatever the function response is,
what i need is just submit in function , let function do its work, even if error occurs inside function .(without try catch)

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this for give you status code 200 by defult.

```
 return redirect()->back()->with(['status' => true, "message" => "", 200]);
```

Comment: This just returns back with code.
Does not execute the code below this function